# Get dictionary pairs for same items from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I want to save the same items from a list (there are always just 2 same items) as pairs into a dictionary. Duplicates are not supposed to appear in the dictionary. This is my code:

```
def find_pairs(list):
    dic = {}
    if list:
        for i, obj in enumerate(list, start=0):
            if obj not in dic:
                for k in xrange(i+1, len(list)):
                    if obj == list[k]:
                        dic[obj] = {list[k]}
    return dic

mylist = ["AE","E","W","B","D","C","AE","W","D","E","C","B"]
res = find_pairs(list)
print(res)  # {'W': {'W'}, 'E': {'E'}, 'C': {'C'}, 'D': {'D'}, 'B': {'B'}, 'AE': {'AE'}}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Maybe I wasn’t clear enough on what I am trying to do. In fact I have a list of objects identifiers. With this objects identifier I can access the object name that will return as a string. Now I need to pair those objects where a certain sector of the string matches with another object from my list. As I did here:

```
def find_pairs(list):
    dic = {}
    if list:
        for i, obj in enumerate(list, start=0):
            if obj not in dic:
                for k in xrange(i+1, len(list)):
                    if return_keyvalue(rs.ObjectName(obj), "_", 4) == return_keyvalue(rs.ObjectName(list[k]), "_", 4):
                        dic[obj] = list[k]
    return(dic)
```

I am just an amateur programmer so I am troubling to implement this in a more clever way.

Comment: this seems extremely wasteful.. Both the code and the end result.

Comment: Can you just just convert your list to a set (removes all duplicates) then create a dictionary and set the key/value to each list/set item?

Comment: also xrange isn't included in python 3, right?

Comment: Correct. `xrange` is not included in Python 3

Comment: I guess there can also be single or more than two appearances in the list? Then you could use `keys = filter(lambda x: mylist.count(x) == 2, mylist)`. Else just do a set from your list.

Comment: Does your list contains always 2 similar items?

Comment: Yes´, at least it should

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
mylist = ["AE","E","W","B","D","C","AE","W","D","E","C","B"]
for i in mylist:
    d[i].add(i)

print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{'D': {'D'}, 'E': {'E'}, 'B': {'B'}, 'AE': {'AE'}, 'W': {'W'}, 'C': {'C'}}
```

Or, an even shorter way:

```
d = {i:set(i) for i in mylist}
```